# Should I create a New Template on WordPress for Each Page?

Tags: wordpress

On a website with 15+ pages, should I use the method of creating a new WordPress template by adding the comment in the HTML file, creating the page in WordPress, and then choosing that template or is there a better/faster way?

All pages are unique so using the same template is not an option.

Comment: If all of your 10 pages use a different structure then yes you'll need to create a template for all of them. Otherwise, if they share the same structure then you can create just one template and use it with all of your pages. Read here for more details: [Theme Handbook | WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/).

Comment: Check the link I shared earlier. It explains everything you want to know and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every page is completely different so yes, you should create each page separately. But if not it's better to use some important template files like `header.php`, `footer.php` and `sidebar.php` and it's very recommended in matter of organizing and **DRY** concept to use `get_template_part()` see the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Answer (score 1):

hi you should create some specific pages like 404.php , page.php , index.php , comments.php and ... all this pages are the most important pages that you should create them and your other pages in web site follow the page.php design .

Comment: for example you create header.php and design it in your other page you use this code : <php get_header(); ?>

Comment: Take a look at this Template Hierarchy link it's handy to know which template is being called https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/